# prevent submit button from redirecting if jquery validation occurs

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has jquery validation. I also have submit button which redirects to page.html when it is clicked. So when I click submit if the value of dropdown is 'please select' the validation appears however it then redirects to page.html. How do I prevent it from doing this? The code for my jquery:

```
<script>      
    $( function(){    
            function validate(id){       
                var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');         
                if(enabled){              
                    //Please select option is selected              
                    if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                 
                    alert('Please select color');                  
                    return false;             
                    }              
                    //Please select option is selected              
                    if($("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                  
                        alert('Please select shade');                  
                        return false;             
                    }   
                }     
                return true;    
            };

            $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function() {  

                var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');      
                $("#colour" + id + ", #shade" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');         
                validate(id);    
            });      
           $("input:submit").click(function(){         
               var retVal = false;
               $.each([1, 2], function(i, val){
                  retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
               });
                return retVal;   
           }); 
         }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: check with the return value from  `validate(val)` and add `event.preventDefault()` at the begining and in the last line you can trigger `submit()` function using `$('#formid').submit()`;

Comment: @run can you check my code: http://pastebin.com/sMJJuRGu and edit if necessary thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tfV4weMn thnx

Comment: @run i think 2nd from last post is closer. submit runs jquery but does not submit info to mysql? yours does this to?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent form submitting call `event.preventDefault()` when validation fails.

Comment: I have added event.preventDefault() into the script. Can you check if i have done it right:  http://pastebin.com/sMJJuRGu . edit if neccessary. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 $( function(){    
        function validate(id){       
            var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');         
            if(enabled){              
                //Please select option is selected              
                if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0 || $("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0)
                {                 
                    alert('Please select color');                
                    return false;             
                }
            } 
            return true;    
        };

        $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function(e) {  

            var id = this.name.replace('attendance', '');      
                $("#colour" + id + ", #shade" + id).prop("disabled", this.value == 'No');         
                validate(id);    
        });      

       $("input:submit").click(function(event){         

            event.preventDefault();
           var retVal = false;
           $.each([1, 2], function(i, val){
              retVal = (validate(val) || retVal);
           });
           if(retVal){$('#formID').submit();}
       }); 
     });
```

Comment: it seems to be working but when clicked on submit, it does not do anything. it should send it to mysql and redirect. the name of submit button matches input:submit. also my form id is list im guessing it is if(retVal){$('list')?

Comment: This will submit your form. To save data in DB you need to post it from form action. eg: <form action="myphp.php" method="post">

And in PHP you can redirect header to related files if data posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { 

    function validate(id){      

        var enabled = ($("input[name='attendance" + id + "']:checked").val() == 'Yes');        
        if(enabled){              
        //Please select option is selected              
        if($("#colour" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){
            alert('Please select color');                  
            return false;   
        }              
        //Please select option is selected              

        if($("#shade" + id)[0].selectedIndex == 0){                 

            alert('Please select shade');                  
            return false;            

        }  

        }    
        return true;    

    }
     $("input[name^='attendance']").click(function() {  
        var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+(,\d+)?/)[0];

        var val = ($(this).val() == 'No') ? true : false;

         $('#colour'+id).attr("disabled", val);
         $('#shade'+id).attr("disabled", val);

         validate(id);    

        });      

        $("input:submit").click(function(event){ 

               event.preventDefault();
               var retVal = false;

               $("input[name^='attendance']").each( function(){

                    var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+(,\d+)?/)[0];
                    retVal = (validate(id) || retVal);

               });

                return retVal;  

           });

});


  </script>
```

in html you missed submit button. and i m not clear with your requirements hope you can modify above code. and get the results

Comment: in @Parag Gajjar example worked but when clicked on submit, it does not do anything but run jquery. it should also submit to database